# Does installing from a persistent liveUSB also copy tools and files downloaded by user?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, live-usb, 14.10, persistence

I have been using ubuntu 14.10 from a persistent liveUSB on my laptop (that is running windows) for the past one week, and have installed some tools and saved some files on the USB. Now, I have a new PC on which I am planning to install ubuntu from this same persistent liveUSB using the "install ubuntu 14.10" application. This way, would I be able to transfer all the tools and files I have downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the files but if you install it will install the default ubuntu desktop without any additional tools or packages.

Probably the easiest way to transfer the files is to first do the install, then before you reboot, mount your fresh install and copy the files.

Assuming you install Ubuntu onto /dev/sda1

```
sudo -i
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
cp your_data /mnt/home/your_new_user
```

Then boot your fresh install, you may need to change ownership of the files

```
sudo chown your_user:your_user -R ~your_user
```

Comment: Thanks! And I assume, those tools that I installed will need to be manually re-installed?

Comment: yes, but that should be rather trivial, you know what you want, just use apt-get or the software center